# flex/bison for embedded bare-metal system

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, cortex-m, bare-metal

I develop software for Cortex M, and for that I use Arm GNU Toolchain.
I need to parse data packages for which I have the grammar.

I have problems with `flex` though, since it normally requires the `libfl.a` library which I don't have compiled for cortex M.

How can I get around this problem (other than recompiling just the `libfl.a` for cortex M)? Maybe some flex parameters?

Also, this raises other doubts for me, since my system is bare-metal:

- I don't have standard I/O functions, I have a custom function that I call `qprintf()`.
- I have no dynamic memory management. I can use FreeRTOS and have, thus, `pvPortMalloc()` instead of the standard `malloc()`.

so I wonder if, even overcoming the `libfl.a` problem, flex and bison would have problems with the constraints mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libfl.a only defines `main` and `yywrap`.  So if you don't need either of those (because you have you own `main` and you either use `%option noyywrap` or you have your own `yywrap`), you don't need libfl.a

However, scanners generated by flex do need `malloc`/`realloc` from the C library, so if you don't have that, you'll need to supply a replacement.  The default `YY_INPUT`/`ECHO` macros also use stdio, so you'll need to redefine (or not use) them if you want to avoid that part of the standard library.

Comment: Is it only scanners generated by flex that use `malloc`? Or are parse generated by bison as well? Is `malloc` used directly by the generated code or indirectly (e.g. by calling `strdup` or `sprintf`)?

Comment: However, there are other problems, for example, the `FILE` type or the `errno` varible

Comment: other problems: `realloc`, `stdin`, `stdout`....

Comment: Bison uses `malloc`/`realloc` as well for managing its stack space.  But this (and stdio/errno) are all part of libc, not libfl

Comment: I have successfully used Ragel for scanner creation. No dependencies and extremely efficient code.